# Angular 5 secure components and prevent preloading

Tags: angular

recently I started to learn angular, 
and I am really concerned about how can I secure the component and prevent component preloading before login or user is logged in but not authorized, I read about the lazy loading and tried it but still I can view the components HTML,CSS and ts files from the browsers source viewer.

my question is: how can I prevent components from preload in browser "user can view the component source" if the user is not authorized?

Comment: There are lot of approaches towards this. You can use Guards which will prevent loading of component if user is not authorized. You can use *ngIf decorator which will check value of specific argument.
EDIT: https://angular.io/guide/router link to clarify

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, Angular does not include anything that helps you preventing the user to load any part of the app. The Angular app should only contain templates (not data).
If it is a problem for you that a user can do reverse engineering to access unauthorized page templates, then maybe the SPA architecture does not fit your needs.

Comment: He didn't post well formatted question. He's newbie to angular and in context, i believe he thought about guards.

Comment: well he's talking about sources, so I guess my understanding was good, wait and see 

Comment: thank you youkouleley, yes I was talking about the sources, but for me its a huge security issue that anyone can do reverse engineering and see what are the unthorized pages templates!

Comment: @laythmorrar I don't know what's the context you're working in, but you should consider server side rendering then. Angular can do it event if it's not its main purpose : https://angular.io/guide/universal